# Set a field based on Spring profile property

Tags: spring-boot

I am using Spring boot and I have several things which I would like to be changed based on the profile I am using (like schedule time, IPs, file names, etc.). I have prod and dev profile. I need a several properties in the profiles which I can use (inject) on given field in some of my classes and the field to be set based on the property and the profile I am using. I never saw such thing in a project but I thing it should be possible. I didnt find anything like this in internet. If my idea is impossible then could you please offer a workaround for my case?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can. Profiles are implemented in almost every application used in production. You basically have as many `application-{profile}.properties` files as many are the profiles, or environments in which you want to run your application(in your case: `prod`, `dev`). So you fill these 2 files with respective properties from their environment. And how do you load the correct file? You pass jvm variable which will define the environment on which the application is running. This property is present in spring boot and it is `spring.profiles.active`. An example of usage is:

```
-Dspring.profiles.active=prod
```

which will set the active profile to `prod`. After you have loaded the profile you can replace the `{profile}` part from the name of the properties file to obtain `application-prod.properties`.

Then, to inject a property value from the file, to a java field you can use the `@Value` annotation like this:

```
@Value("${start_time}")
private String start_time;
```

You can find more details [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-profiles.html), [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html) and [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html).

Comment: I know this but its not my point. I want to right a property for example start_time=2018-06-18 in my dev profile and start_time=2019-01-01 in my prod prifile, then to use the value of start_time in some of my classes and replace for example public static String time variable with start_time from my current loaded profile on load.

Comment: So you want to mix values from `dev` and `prod`?

Comment: Or you want to just inject property value from the file in java property?

Comment: I want to inject property from current profile into a given field of given class

Comment: @dimilalabar Check the update with `@Value` annotation.

Comment: PERFECT Thanks !